# Azure App Service with Authentication using KeyCloak

Tags: azure-web-app-service, keycloak

While deploying keycloak image to azure appservice, I would like to change this "http://localhost:8080/auth" to something https://appservicekeycloak.azurewebsites.net/auth/.

Not sure how it can be configured.
[image]

Comment: Found some documentation .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-authentication-app-service

Answer (score 0):

You need create a new entry here:

[image]

After that, add this entry:

[image]

With that:

```
https://appservicekeycloak.azurewebsites.net/auth/
```

Or your custom URL.

That's all.